# VSTS Hosted Agent - MSB3021 Unable to Copy File There is not enough disk space

Tags: azure-pipelines

On Hosted Agent, I am getting "MSB3021 unable to copy file There is not enough space on the disk."

I need more information about Hosted Agent Storage. Here, it says it provides 10GB of storage.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted

Does agent have 10GB for all the software installed on it as well as code+build output, or just for code+build output? Is there anyway to see what is taking up space? Build on my local build server is 2.5GB (code+build output).

This is part of the path from the agent build log:

```
d:\a\3\s\
```

I presume folders represent: `a` is agent, `3` is agent number, and `s` is source. Is this 10GB per agent or per host? If host has say 4 agents, is 10GB shared across all 4 agents?

Comment: Try to get the disk space info by using this PowerShell (Add PowerShell step/task): Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk -filter "deviceid='D:'" -ComputerName localhost | Select PSComputername,DeviceID,@{Name="SizeGB";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}},@{Name="FreeGB";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1GB,2)}}   The result of mine is 12.8G

Comment: I ended up rolling private agent, as 10GB was not enough for single build.

Comment: A private agent is better, because it can just download the updated files to agent if set clean up to false.

Comment: Is there a way to clean the hosted agent and also a cleanup step added in the build process to make sure the hosted agent is cleaned each time?

Comment: The way I understand it, hosted agent is new every build, so clean is not as useful, as you every time download whole source defined in get step.